# Adding values into array in while loop overriding old values

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

This is my code:

```
if ( 0 < $matches->total() ) {
    while ( $matches->fetch() ) {
        ?>
            <?php $ma1_winner      = $matches->display( 'winner' ); ?>
            <?php $ma1_team_1      = $matches->display( 'team_1' ); ?> 
            <?php $matches_array_1['winner'] = $ma1_winner; ?>
                <?php $matches_array_1['team1'] = $ma1_team_1; ?>
            <?php
                    } // end of while loop
            } // end of if any exists
            ?>


            <?php var_dump($matches_array_1); ?>
            <?php die(); ?>
```

But it outputs in var_dump only one winner and team not 15 from my database. How to fix it?

Comment: You only need/should only have one open/close pair of `<?php ?>` for that entire block of code.

Comment: Yeah, I know php tags are not a problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each iteration, append a new array with `winner` and `team` as its keys. The result will be a 2-dimensional array containing all your values.

```
while ($matches->fetch() {
  // Append a new array via [] = array()
  // for every loop iteration
  $matches_array_1[] = array(
     'winner'=>$matches->display('winner'), 
     'team'=>$matches->display('team')
  );
}
var_dump($matches_array_1);
```

Otherwise, you are just overwriting the same two keys `winner` and `team` on every iteration.

Comment: working! great, thanks a lot. Could I ask you why my code was not working?

Comment: @Derfder Yours didn't work because on every loop iteration, you were just setting the keys `winner,team` of a 1-dimensional array to the current loop's fetched values.  Over and over, you overwrote the same two array keys.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, I will tick your answer in 6 minutes according to the popup

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of unique match identifier for each match when constructing the array. Something like:

```
<?
if ( 0 < $matches->total() ) 
{
    while ( $matches->fetch() ) 
    {
        $matches_array_1[$matches->display('match_id')]['winner'] = $matches->display( 'winner' );
        $matches_array_1[$matches->display('match_id')]['team1']  = $matches->display( 'team_1' );
    } // end of while loop
} // end of if any exists
var_dump($matches_array_1); 
die();
?>
```